# The specified configuration is invalid. Update the fields as indicated for each tab

Tags: sql-server, tfs, ssas

I am following the [official guide to add Tfs Reporting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/add-a-report-server) to an existing TFS server:

This is what it should look like:

[image]

This is what mine looks like:

[image]

> The SQL Server and instance that you specified was not found or cannot be reached. Specify another server or instance.

When I click OK I get this error message:

> The specified configuration is invalid. Update the fields as indicated for each tab.

I saw this thread on [MSDN with the above error message](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfcb3031-c19a-474d-aab4-3b88ecd248e1/cannot-connect-to-reporting-server?forum=tfsreporting) and although its to do with SSRS (not SSAS) it says to have SSRS configured as Native:

[image]

I restarted the SQL Analysis Service as per this thread which was marked as a solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/215494bd-7914-4451-aacb-7c3ca9cb2663/sql-server-and-instance-that-you-specified-was-not-found-or-cannot-be-reachedtfs-2012-upgrade?forum=tfsintegration

I even tried creating the Tfs_Analysis database (just so I knew it existed), but still same problem.

Any ideas on what to try next?

Comment: What happens when you click Test Connection?

Comment: That's the thing, it faiis with the `The SQL Server and instance that you specified was not found or cannot be reached error.` I am sa of the db and will try tomorrow using specific sa creds I've always done it through TFS install. The db server via this service account is accessible.

Comment: And you're certain that your db server is the default instance? Can you connect through SSMS and show the resulting connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work if your SQL server doesn't have the Browser services running, you need to explicitly list the port.
For the Analysis services tab that is entered in the format of `SERVERNAME:PORT`. Note that everytime you open this window, TFS will seem to forget about that port and you have to re-enter it in order to fix it.
Using the TfsConfig commandline might be better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#remapdbs

**Edit:** See OP's answer for further info.

Answer (score 0):

1. The SQL server Browser service wasn't running (thxs nschonni)
2. Then I followed this blog post: http://chamindac.blogspot.com.au/2015/05/resolve-tf255050-connection-cannot-be.html?_sm_au_=i6VBJsNvmH3qMTBN

   - Check WMI service is running
   - Check the SQL Firewall Ports 1433 & 1434
   - I added the Firewall ports for SQL Analysis Server: 2382 & 2383